# If $g:R^m \to R^n$ has derivative $\lambda$ at $a$, is the limit as $x\to 0$ of $\frac{|g(a + x) - g(a)|}{|x|}$ always $\|\lambda\|$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am able to show the limit is bounded above by $\|\lambda\|$ if it exists: $$\frac{|g(a +x) - g(a)|}{|x|} \leq \frac{|g(a+ x) - g(a) - \lambda x|}{|x|} + \|\lambda\|$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the answer is yes. Since:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left|\left|\frac{g(x + a) - g(a)}{x} - \lambda \right|\right| = 0$$

Now we can use the squeeze theorem. First a lemma: For any vectors $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $-\|a - b\| \leq \|a\| - \|b\| \leq \|a - b\|$. You can prove this using the triangle inequality: $\|a - b + b\| \leq \|a - b\| + \|b\|$, so $\|a\| - \|b\| \leq \|a - b\|$, this is the right inequality. The left inequality is given by switching $a$ and $b$: $\|b\| - \|a\| \leq \|b - a\|$, then multiply by $-1$.

So:

$$-\left|\left|\frac{g(x + a) - g(a)}{x} - \lambda \right|\right| \leq \frac{\|g(x + a) - g(a)\|}{\|x\|} - \|\lambda\| \leq \left|\left|\frac{g(x + a) - g(a)}{x} - \lambda \right|\right|$$

The squeeze theorem implies that the middle goes to zero as well.

Now what if $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$? A simple case is $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(u,v) = v$. Then setting $a = 0$:

$$\frac{\|g(u,v) - g(0,0)\|}{\|(u,v)\|} = \frac{|v|}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}$$

And this limit does not exist as $(u,v) \rightarrow (0,0)$.

Comment: But $g$ is assumed to be differentiable at $a$, so your counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: $g$ is differentiable at $a$. (It's smooth everywhere, in fact). Its derivative is $\begin{bmatrix}g_u & g_v \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Dang it…  Stupidly, I was thinking about complex derivative (as $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}$).  You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

That limit hardly ever exists. For example, take $g:\mathbb {R}^2\to \mathbb {R}$ defined by $g(x,y) = x.$ Then

$$|g((0,0)+(x,y)) - g((0,0))|/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} = |x|/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2},$$

which doesn't have a limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0).$

My guess is the limit exists iff $\lambda $ is a scalar multiple of a linear isometry.